# Laravel setting filesystem path in circle ci?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, circleci

The main issue is that when I run phpunit in circleci with a test that requires the creation of folders and files it fails.

Folder creation is done with:

```
$path = 'pdf-files';
$fullPath = sprintf('%s/%s', storage_path(), $path);
File::makeDirectory($fullPath, 0775, true, true);
```

The test are green and passing locally but it does fails in CircleCi because the files are being saved in `/var/www/project`, but for some reason the application keeps looking for the folder and files in `/home/ubuntu/project` even tho the application is saving the file in another locacation.

What is the best way to fix this issue?

Comment: You can replace `$fullpath` with `storage_path($path)`